# Correct way to display row name/label

Tags: usability, tables, nested-tables

I want to display label (or name) for second row in a table so users know about what that row contains, please see image.

Please note: On left there is another grid, thus adding name/label for the row on left isn't possible.

[image]

A solution, I think of is to add a legend along side table name text with background similar to the row (similar to colored legends for charts). Although, not sure if that will help.

[image]

Please suggest or provide feedback to make it better.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello NavenS. I'm trying to figure out how your data is grouped. What do you mean by "on the left there is another grid"? Is this data related to your data for the table you're struggling with? Why does it need to be attached to the table you're asking about? Can you provide more information about how your data is organized and related so we can get a better idea of how it should be displayed? Also, regarding the cells labeled "col", are those column headers? Why do they take up two columns while the cells below merge into one column?

Comment: @Navens, it looks like the last column (Week 13) is cut off. Does that mean the whole table is in a horizontally scrolling pane?

Comment: Hi @maxathousand, apologies for not for explaining clearly. I have updated the question. Both Left table and Week table are related, by means of some data. The Col name is column headings for Left table. The week number forms column headings for week table. The second row of week table has editable inputs. Now this specific row must be labeled somehow for user to know what data it holds. Any inputs on how it can be done. We can add placeholder text, but these can be empty cells sometimes.

Comment: @KenMohnkern, yes the tables are in horizontally scrolling panes

Comment: @NavenS - Does each of your text fields need its own label in its table cell? Or just one label for the whole row? If the latter, then why not just add a column for the row labels? More columns will be outside of view, but the scrollable pane will take care of that.

Comment: @KenMohnkern- I need only one label for the whole row. I can't have an additional column for the row labels, as other rows don't need those.

Comment: Well, there is no right or wrong solution for this, adding an extra column to label the just the one row when there are over 20+ columns to scroll isn't ideal. For now I have added Factor text within the empty cells (as there will be) and placeholders to the text boxes, it looks repeated but does the job of conveying the type of content within the row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding your question completely, but would something like this work?
[image]

Alternatively, you can just create a new sheet

Comment: thanks for answer, but I can't have row names on left per the image you added. I need to somehow add an identifier (or name) for the row immediately follows the column heading row of Week table.

Comment: Can you move the second table into a new sheet? Some context and constraints would really help in providing a better answer.

Comment: @NavenS please post and share you solution, and then accept it as the right answer then :)

Comment: For now I have added word "Factor" inside empty cells and text boxes (as placeholder), it looks repeated but does the job of conveying the type of content for the row.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how Excel or google sheets handle relational data.

[image: screenshot of excel]

When the field "tomorrow" is selected, Excel marks the referenced column. You can also click on another id to change the referenced column.